# Best simple linux cmd tool for offline transaction creation and signing?

Tags: message-signing

I tried to use sx, but it no longer works since bip62 (malleability fix). Nodes don't accept generated transactions, saying "high S signature".

What offline command-line tool would be the best?

Comment: Please don't use the "edit" function to vandalize your own post.  There is a "delete" button; use that instead if you really want to.  But three people have found your question useful, so you might consider leaving it.  If you wanted to delete the question because you found the answer, consider adding your own answer, so that it can be of use to others.

Answer (score 2):

There are many command line tools for creating and signing raw transactions offline, most of them written in Python: [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin), [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib), [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) and others.

If you use [Electrum](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum) wallet, it has command line tools for offline transaction creation and signing:

```
$ ./electrum help createrawtx
$ ./electrum help signtransaction
```